# What are the most used Accept-Language in HTTP header?

Tags: http-headers

I make website and want to use the Accept-Language in HTTP header to help visitor find their language. However, I have a hard time to find statistics about the use of Accept-Language.

1. Will most visitor have something set as their Accept-Language? Some places it is written things like "most modern browsers support Accept-Language", but do anyone have overview of which specific browser versions that support it? And will usually browser language be set as Accept-Language by default if the user don't actively change their own Accept-Language settings? I guess most people don't change these settings, but that doesn't mean that Accept-Language is left blank?
2. Do anyone have statistics for the most used language codes set inside Accept-Language? I can make mapping system to map them with my site languages, but I also have problem to find some good statistics about most used codes. It would help a lot to get the overview for how to make this work better!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found this link:
http://shipmodeling.net/vb_forum/statistic-tld.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oswald said, by default browsers set this to the language used by the browser UI. So no, the default setting isn't blank, it's something like "en-US,en".

The only figures that I have found are on https://panopticlick.eff.org/results?#fingerprintTable . That page tests for the amount of information contained in HTTP requests. On the test result page, after clicking on "Show full results for fingerprinting", for various pieces of information it shows their frequency in column "one in x browsers have this value".

In row "HTTP_ACCEPT Headers" it shows the frequency of a combination of some Accept header values given by the browser. For example, it says that one in 5.25 browsers send the value "text/html, */*; q=0.01 gzip, deflate, br en-US,en;q=0.5". Unfortunately, that value seems to be the concatenation of the values of headers "Accept" (somewhat stripped), "Accept-Encoding", and "Accept-Language", with a "br" thrown in for good measure.

As I wrote, when I experimented with panopticlick, it showed "one in 5.25 requests" for "en-US,en". This value is one of the more common ones, if not the most common one. One in 295.2 requests had just "en-US", one in 547.18 requests had just "en" and one in 1076.94 requests had "en,en-US" (which should have the same effects as "en", so it does not really make sense to use it).

Varying only the configuration of accepted languages, we can infer the frequency of the languages as seen by panopticlick. A more direct way would of course be to simply write to them and ask them for a table. I'm sure that the sample set of panopticlick is not representative for the entire internet, but at least it's a start.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers send an Accept-Language header field out of the box. By default, the same language is requested, that is used for the user interface of the browser.